# What percentage of players get into each league tier?

Tags: starcraft-2

E.g., if I'm in the Silver league, this means I'm generally/statistically better than what percentage of the players?

(At least for the first qualifying matches, that is)

Comment: Related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6347/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know what it is by design but I can provide statistics on a per region basis.  Bare in mind, this is where players are, not where they belong (so they maybe better or worse than they appear).

```
Region          Diamond         Plat             Gold              Silver           Bronz
Global          5.48% (25,969)  16.03% (75,970)  21.58% (102,249)  21.28% (100,830) 35.62% (168,781)
North America   5.29% (10,831)  17.61% (36,060)  21.53% (44,102)   19.58% (40,109)  35.99% (73,709)
Europe          5.34% (7,604)   15.65% (22,297)  21.02% (29,944)   20.78% (29,615)  37.22% (53,028)
Korea           6.53% (3,437)   14.44% (7,599)   23.66% (12,451)   26.05% (13,709)  29.32% (15,433)
Taiwan          5.68% (1,663)   13.04% (3,820)   22.03% (6,451)    24.73% (7,241)   34.53% (10,111)
Southeast Asia  5.03% (1,170)   13.55% (3,151)   20.99% (4,882)    22.66% (5,272)   37.77% (8,786)
Russia          5.96% (952)     14.11% (2,253)   20.17% (3,222)    22.63% (3,614)   37.14% (5,932)
Latin America   5.83% (312)     14.76% (790)     22.37% (1,197)    23.73% (1,270)   33.30% (1,782)
```

These numbers would seem to suggest the following:

- Diamond: 95th Percentile
- Plat: 80th Percentile
- Gold: 60th Percentile
- Silver: 40-35th Percentile
- Bronze: 1st Percentile

---

Update:

At Blizzcon 2010 Blizzard announced that they would add two new leagues with the following requirements:

- Grand Master: Top 200 players
- Master: 98th Percentile

Comment: Are those statistics available on some web page?

Comment: @Michal yes, information can be found here: http://sc2ranks.com/

Answer (score 1):

Updated figures as of today are as follows (all the raw #s in the first table refer to the # of pages of divisions, so multiply by 100 to get actual numbers, +/- a few)

## 1v1 2v2R 3v3R 4v4R 2v2T 3v3T 4v4T Totals

Diamond 370 125 144 105 130 23 4 901

Plat 784 268 292 215 484 159 52 2,254

Gold 964 449 442 377 756 309 125 3,422

Silver 927 507 469 391 927 394 161 3,776

Bronze 1,984 874 508 358 1,787 1,094 385 6,990

Total 5,029 2,223 1,855 1,446 4,084 1,979 727 17,343

% 1v1 2v2R 3v3R 4v4R 2v2T 3v3T 4v4T Totals

Diamond 7.4% 5.6% 7.8% 7.3% 3.2% 1.2% 0.6% 5.2%

Plat 15.6% 12.1% 15.7% 14.9% 11.9% 8.0% 7.2% 13.0%

Gold 19.2% 20.2% 23.8% 26.1% 18.5% 15.6% 17.2% 19.7%

Silver 18.4% 22.8% 25.3% 27.0% 22.7% 19.9% 22.1% 21.8%

Bronze 39.5% 39.3% 27.4% 24.8% 43.8% 55.3% 53.0% 40.3%

EDIT: Trying to make it format a bit better.

Comment: [Here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/f6241f0c-a157-4a9a-9c1a-3ef16e774980/view-source) is the source of the other answer, you can use it as a baseline to construct your table. And don't forget to check out the [Markdown Help](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if you haven't already ♪