# How many divisions are there for each league in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Starcraft 2 competitive online games you get placed in a league and are ranked against approximately 100 other people of your skill level.

For the different skill levels there are *bronze*, *silver*, *gold*, *platinum* and *diamond* leagues, but each of these levels is divided into several "divisions" of 100 people.

How many such divisions are there for each level?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starcraft 2 Divisions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5763/starcraft-2-divisions)

Comment: @JavadocMD he asked how many, not what divisions mean, or how they're assigned

Comment: The number of divisions are not set in stone, as they will increase in number as the total number of people playing starcraft multiplayer likewise increase.

Any correct numerical answer will no longer be valid in a month or so, only the percentages should remain constant.

Comment: @tzenes: the other question also asks how many.

Comment: @JavadocMD you are correct, I must have missed that.  This brings up a larger issue: if your question is part of another question, but was not answered as part of that question, should you cut a new question?

Comment: @tzenes: that's a good question for meta :) but in this case, it was also answered in the top-voted submission: "There can be up to 100 players in any division. The game will create as many divisions as it needs to fit everybody who played their placement matches into one."

Comment: @JavadocMD I'm not sure that's actually an answer to his question.  Obviously the number changes and its based on player number, but if he's considering something along the lines of "Well I want to know how I'm placed against all divisions, how much work is that going to take?" Telling him there is an arbitrary number isn't helpful.  By comparison, ballparking the number will discourage him from that behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time of this writing there are:

```
Type      Total     Russia  Taiwan   SE Asia   Europe  Korea    NA    Latin America 
 All      25,670     862     1,707    1,299     7,371  2,678  11,380       373
```

Broken down by Type and League (approximate numbers)

```
 X          1v1         2v2         3v3         4v4        2Rand        3Rand        4Rand
Diamond     700         200          50          25         200          200          100
Plat       1400         700         200          50         400          400          300
Gold       1900        1100         400         200         700          700          500
Silver     1900        1300         500         200         800          700          500
Bronze     3500        2600        1600         600        1400          800          400
Total      9400        5900        2700        1050        3500         2800         1800
```

This data was tabulated by myself based on the website: http://sc2ranks.com/

As to what that split represents, I refer you to this question:
[What percentage of players get into each league tier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4767)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer would be as many as there need to be.

Here is a good article talking about the new ladder system:

[Divisions Explained](http://lorehound.com/starcraft/starcraft-2s-battle-net-leagues-ladders-and-rankings-explained/)

They are split up *approximately* like so:
    * Diamond (top 10%)
    * Platinum (10-25%)
    * Gold (25-45%)
    * Silver (45-70%)
    * Bronze (70-100%)

Comment: Your numbers are slightly off: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4767

Answer (score 0):

total number of players = x, multiplied by percent of league P (ie. diamond would multiply by .1), divided by 100. (x*P/100). this would give an approximate answer for number of divisions.